# How do I instance a java generic Class?

Tags: javascript, generics, nativescript

I need to instance a native java class in my NativeScript(JavaScript) code.

I've seen at official documentation how to instance a native java class ([Official Doc - Java to Js](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/java-to-js.html)), although there isn't any consideration about generic classes.

Eg:

```
var newObject = new SomeClass<Type>();
```

That code above throws an exception.

**UPDATE:**

As a workaround I created a java Class that wraps the generics class and compiled and exported as a JAR file, so I could call it from JavaScript code as the official documentation explains:

Eg:

```
public class GenericListStringWrapper implements List<String> {

}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: *That code throws an excpetion* Which one??

Answer (score 3):

There is no syntax in Javascript to instantiate a Java class with generic types.

Even if there was, there is not much to be gained from it, as (a) Javascript is not a typed language, so you won't get compile-time type checking anyway (which is what generics are there to improve) and (b) generic types in Java are erased at runtime, so that they cannot be of use after compile-time either.

So, you can just stick with

```
 var newObject = new SomeClass();
```